# JQuery AJAX append to appended element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, append

I am using RoR with AJAX to create posts. So I need an ability to add an 'answers' by previous id.
Every time submit button clicked following code being called

```jquery
$("<%= selector %>").append("<div id='<%= newanswer %>'><%= escape_javascript(render('answer_layout')) %></div>");
```

where
`selector` looks like this `#answer-12`
`newanswer` would be `#answer-13`

First time it works as suggested, but when I click submit second time I need to use already appended `#answer-13` div to append newly `#answer-14`, and it doesn't work. I understand that document doesn't know about first appended element, but have no idea how to resolve this issue. Thanks for any help.

**UPDATED**
I render new `answer` with edit and destroy links, so I need not only an ability to append which could be workarounded, but fully interact with added elements

Comment: `newanswer` should not have the starting `#` sign

Comment: @F.Calderan. He just saying it's id is `answer-13`

Comment: gdoron right, ofc there is no `#` in id name. `newanswer` is `answer-13`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a wrapper div for all the answers as append adds to the the end of the currently selected element.

So have `$('#answer-div').append(etc.....`

Instead of `$('#specific-answer').append(etc...`

Answer (score 1):

Give all the answers a class, and select the last:

```
$('.theClass:last').append("<div id='<%= newanswer %>'><%= escape_javascript(render('answer_layout')) %></div>");
```

Or use this:

```
$('[id^="answer-"]:last').append("<div id='<%= newanswer %>'><%= escape_javascript(render('answer_layout')) %></div>");
```

---

**jQuery('[attribute^="value"]')**
`attribute`- An attribute name.
`value`-  An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But I can't use 1st variant and the 2nd is kind of hardcode, because it will not work if the rules would be changed or for mixed answers

Comment: @ArcaneRain. Do you have a better option...?

Comment: Don't have for now, Beniot's solution will work for mixed answers, but I believe there is a way to initialize appended element in the DOM tree to work with it, because in my real app answer contains subform for comments which I need to use, like here, in stackoverflow, and after appending an answer I need an ability to add a comments etc

Answer (score 0):

I can just make a suggestion that you could place somewhere in the DOM your latest used ID:

```
var appendTo = $('#append-to');    
var appendToId = appendTo.attr('latest');
$( '#' + appendToId ).append("<div id='<%= newanswer %>'><%= escape_javascript(render('answer_layout')) %></div>");

appendTo.attr( 'latest', '<%= newanswer %>' );
```